# Wrong ")" with Libertine+xurl in xelatex Overleaf

Tags: xetex, overleaf, libertine, xurl

I get quite strange parentheses in `\url{}` when load `libertine` and `xurl` packages together in `xelatex` Overleaf.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xurl}
\begin{document}
    \url{((()))}
\end{document}
```

The code above gives

[image]

Disable either package will give normal parentheses. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Under TeXLive 2022 I get the same (proper) output for pdflatex, xelatex and lualatex. SO what version/latex dist are you using?

Comment: Oh I'm using overleaf, the latest version available is 2021

Comment: That is very important information that you should add to your question. Testing with my old TL installations, the issue is **not** present in fully up to date TexLive 2021, but the Overleaf TL21 is **not** fully up to date as they don't generally update packages. In my setup the problem **is** present in TL20 for xelatex and lualatex, but not pdflatex.

Comment: Thanks for your check, your comment could be a solution to this question.

Comment: I added a summation. Note that I also added the `overleaf` tag to your question (you should really update your question to make it clear that this is related to Overleaf as it is rather important).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed via updates to TeXLive 2021. At least when I test with

- TeXLive 2022: no issues, expected output
- TeXLive 2021 frozen (aka all available updates): no issue, expected output
- TeXLive 2020 frozen: Here I see the same output as the OP for `xelatex` and `lualatex`, whereas `pdflatex` give the proper output.

My conclusion is that this was fixed during the update cycle for TeXLive 2021. But generally Overleaf does not update packages during the cycle, so that fix has not made it to Overleaf for their TeXLive 2021 installation.

Comment: And what is the fix?

Comment: @HenriMenke No idea, I can just see that fully opdated TL21 shows the correct output, whereas fully updated TL20 does not.

Comment: @HenriMenke I can see that at least `xurl` was updated in early 2022 and was from 2020 before that. But that change does not seem to matter (they added `)` etc as URL break points and adding that change to and running the doc with TL20, does not change anything)